# Optimize "not in" query

Tags: sql

Please help optimize this query:

```
SELECT ts.SiteId, COUNT(ts.SiteId) AS Count 
FROM ts 
WHERE ts.SiteId not in 
   (SELECT ts.SiteId FROM ts WHERE ts.uniqueid = 'xxx') 
GROUP BY ts.SiteId ORDER BY Count DESC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT ts.SiteId, COUNT(ts.SiteId) AS Count, 
MAX(CASE WHEN ts.uniqueid = 'xxx' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As XXXUniqueID
FROM ts 
GROUP BY ts.SiteId
HAVING XXXUniqueID = 0
ORDER BY Count DESC
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking. Additionally, if you don't want the extra column to be returned, you can probably move the entire `MAX(...)` expression into the `HAVING` clause instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used this:

SELECT ts.SiteId, COUNT(ts.SiteId) AS Count FROM ts 
GROUP BY ts.SiteId
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN ts.uniqueid = 'xxx' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
ORDER BY Count DESC

Comment: I like the answer, but I'd like to know conceptually why this would perform any better.  Perhaps there's a difference in JOIN type?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL 2005 CTE, it might look like this:

```
;
WITH 
e AS
(
    SELECT ts.SiteId FROM ts 
    EXCEPT
    SELECT ts.SiteId FROM ts WHERE ts.uniqueid = 'xxx'
)
SELECT e.SiteId, COUNT(e.SiteId) AS Count 
FROM e
GROUP BY e.SiteId ORDER BY Count DESC
```